# c static method calls with friendly method name

Tags: c++, methods, header

I have a header file `helper.h`

```
class helper
{

public:
    static int someVal();   
};

int helper::someVal()
{
   return 999;
}
```

In my c class I call the `someVal` method as follows

```
#include "helper.h"
.
.
int answer = helper::someVal();
```

Is there way to have a call like this instead?

```
int answer = someVal();
```

Solution from below is 
    helper.h --

```
static int someVal();   

 int someVal()
    {
        return 999;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly, but you can make `helper` a namespace instead of a class:

```
namespace helper
{
    static int someVal();   
}

using namespace helper;
int answer = someVal();
```

You can define the function just as you did in the question. In practice is's often better to not use `using namespace` for your own functions because that makes it easier to understand which function is called.

Comment: There is also the option of storing the static function address in a function pointer that has friendlier name. But it does seem more a more artificial solution than yours. +1.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But how does a call to printf (part of stdio.h) work without a using or doing something like stdio::printf ?

Comment: printf is not part of a class called stdio. This is not Java, functions need not live in a class.

Comment: Ignoring where printf lives, there is a way to call it without specifying the class or namespace, how is this done?

Comment: Yes, but stdio.h is not a class, it is a header. And, by doing what you did you include the C-version of the header (remember, C does not even have classes). If (for whatever reason) you need printf in C++, you should #include <cstdio> and then you find it in `namespace` std. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: For the case of *how it is done* when including stdio.h, it's just as if you would have declared `static int someVal();` without either a helper class or a helper namespace.

Comment: There it is. Thank you. Been swithing between too many languages and didn't realise you could have methods not in a class.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a class with `static` functions, you could use a `namespace` with functions instead. You could later use `using namespace` to access the function without the namespace name.

Answer (score 0):

why should you want to? someone reading the code (even yourself in near future) is very happ not to misinterpret the function as global. when you do good naming on class and member function you would miss important information without class name. `Factory::get_instance()` carries more information than `get_instance()`.